# Angular JS controller element is undefined when called in directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a controller like so:

```
myApp.controller('WizardController', function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.user = {
    addressline1: null,
    cobuyer: null,
    validate: null,
    cobuyerfirstname: null,
    cobuyerlastname: null,
    cobuyeremail: null,
    cobuyerdob: null,
    cobuyeraddressline1: null,
    cobuyeraddressline2: null,
    cobuyercity: null,
    cobuyerprovince: null,
    cobuyerpostalcode: null,
    cobuyerphone: null,
    dobString: null,
    cobuyerDobString: null,
    isWaitList: false
};

});
```

and I add this directive below:

```
myApp.directive('checkbox', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            user: '='
        },
        template: '<label for="addressSame" class="form-label col-md-2" style="width: auto;">Same as Buyers Address</label><input type="checkbox" name="addressSame" ng-click="isSameAddress()" ng-model="isChecked" />',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // Initialize to unchecked
            scope.isChecked = false;

        },
        controller: function ($scope) {

            $scope.isSameAddress = function () {

                console.log($scope.isChecked);

                if ($scope.isChecked == true) {
                    console.log($scope.user);
                }
                else {

                }
            }

        }
    }
});
```

Now my checkbox appears as it should, I am able to check it and get the true or false from scope.isChecked. I am now trying to get items from $scope.user, but it says its undefined. I am fairly new to Angular JS and I have no idea how to fix this...How do i get an element that is defined in the controller?

I have also tried this, still undefined:

```
myApp.directive('checkbox', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            user: '='
        },
        template: '<label for="addressSame" class="form-label col-md-2" style="width: auto;">Same as Buyers Address</label><input type="checkbox" name="addressSame" ng-click="isSameAddress()" ng-model="isChecked" />',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // Initialize to unchecked
            scope.isChecked = false;

        },
        controller: function ($scope, $http, $rootScope) {

            $scope.isSameAddress = function () {

                console.log($scope.isChecked);

                if ($scope.isChecked == true) {
                    console.log($rootScope.user);
                }
                else {

                }
            }

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: can you to define the $scope.user in the directive controller itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `$scope` is only visible inside the controller itself;
You can use `$rootScope` (just remenber that it's a global variable);
Try to change from `$scope.user` to `$rootScope.user`.

Comment: I tried that I get this error `$rootScope is not defined`

Comment: @user979331, it's a global scope, but not a global variable, you need to inject it in your controller/service : `function ($scope, $http, $rootScope) {`

Comment: New error: Unknown provider: $routeScopeProvider <- $routeScope

Comment: controller: function ($scope, $http, $routeScope) {

Comment: @user979331 it's a typo, change to `$rootScope` (not `$routeScope`)

Comment: still undefined.

Comment: you also need to inject it into your directive and replace $scope with $rootScope

Comment: I updated my question with what I just tried, can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do yourself a **HUGE** favor and avoid $rootScope like the plague. It will only lead to components that are highly coupled to your app and not provide you any benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
myApp.controller('WizardController', ['$scope', function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.user = {
    addressline1: null,
    cobuyer: null,
    validate: null,
    cobuyerfirstname: null,
    cobuyerlastname: null,
    cobuyeremail: null,
    cobuyerdob: null,
    cobuyeraddressline1: null,
    cobuyeraddressline2: null,
    cobuyercity: null,
    cobuyerprovince: null,
    cobuyerpostalcode: null,
    cobuyerphone: null,
    dobString: null,
    cobuyerDobString: null,
    isWaitList: false
};

}]);
```

Comment: The problem is probably not minification of his/her code. Besides your example would need to look like this:

    `myApp.controller('WizardController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {`

I think the problem is related to how he/she is getting the `user` object from the outer controller into the directive. See my explanation below

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('checkbox', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        transclude: true,
        $scope: {
            user: '='
        },
        template: '<label for="addressSame" class="form-label col-md-2" style="width: auto;">Same as Buyers Address</label><input type="checkbox" name="addressSame" ng-click="isSameAddress()" ng-model="isChecked" /> <span ng-if="isChecked"> {{user|json}}</span>',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            // Initialize to unchecked
            $scope.isChecked = false;
            console.log($scope.user)

        },
        controller: function ($scope) {

            $scope.isSameAddress = function () {

                console.log($scope.isChecked);

                if ($scope.isChecked === true) {
                    console.log($scope.user);
                }
                else {

                }
            }

        }
    }
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.user = {
    addressline1: null,
    cobuyer: null,
    validate: null,
    cobuyerfirstname: null,
    cobuyerlastname: null,
    cobuyeremail: null,
    cobuyerdob: null,
    cobuyeraddressline1: null,
    cobuyeraddressline2: null,
    cobuyercity: null,
    cobuyerprovince: null,
    cobuyerpostalcode: null,
    cobuyerphone: null,
    dobString: null,
    cobuyerDobString: null,
    isWaitList: false
};
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p checkbox="user">Hello</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: try this. if face any problem see in [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/AtHdaNwdatriG99p6UWT?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any other code it is hard to know exactly what you are doing. So I made some assumptions:

- I assumed that your controller `WizardController` was an outer
  controller.
- I assume that you really were not using transclusion
  since your template didn't use it. So I removed `transclude: true`
  from the directive.
- I formatted the code to fit my style. I find is easier to break out my
  functions from  the angular registration code. and group things together.
  I also added code to handle minification if you were planning to do that.
- I never embed my controller code within my directives. This fits the
  [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)
  a little better.

I will give more detail below.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    // Controller code for application
    AppController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http']; // <- This is needed only if you plan to minify your JS code.
    function AppController($scope, $http) {
      $scope.user = {
        addressline1: '', // <-- Since these values will display in the HTML use an empty string instead of null
        cobuyer: '',
        validate: '',
        cobuyerfirstname: 'John',
        cobuyerlastname: 'Smith',
        cobuyeremail: 'myEmail@example.com',
        cobuyerdob: '',
        cobuyeraddressline1: '123 Some Street',
        cobuyeraddressline2: '',
        cobuyercity: 'Anchorage',
        cobuyerprovince: '',
        cobuyerpostalcode: '99501',
        cobuyerphone: '',
        dobString: '',
        cobuyerDobString: '',
        isWaitList: false
      };
    }

    // Controller code for directive `checkbox`
    CheckboxController.$inject = ['$scope']; // <- This is needed only if you plan to minify your JS code.
    function CheckboxController($scope) {
      $scope.isChecked = false; // <-- Put all scope variables into the controller.

      $scope.isSameAddress = function () { // <-- put all of your scope functions in the controller.
        console.log('$scope.isChecked', $scope.isChecked);

        if ($scope.isChecked == true) {
          console.log('$scope.user', $scope.user);
        }
        else {

        }
      }
    }

    // Directive code for attribute `checkbox`
    function checkboxDirective() {
      return {
        controller: 'CheckboxController', // <-- I link to my controller and avoid adding the controller code here.
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        scope: {
          user: '='
        },
        template: '<label for="addressSame" class="form-label col-md-2" style="width: auto;">Same as Buyers Address</label><input type="checkbox" name="addressSame" ng-click="isSameAddress()" ng-model="isChecked" />'
      }
    }

    // Angular registration code
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller('AppController', AppController);
    myApp.controller('CheckboxController', CheckboxController);
    myApp.directive('checkbox', checkboxDirective);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="AppController">
    <div checkbox user="user"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In your example you didn't show us how you were getting `user` into your directive. Based on your code example it should have been passed in through the `user` attribute. Like this:

```
<div checkbox user="user"></div>
```

Since you are using an `Attribute` based directive you could have also used the `checked` attribute instead of the `user` attribute like this:

```
// Directive code for attribute `checkbox`
function checkboxDirective() {
  return {
    controller: 'CheckboxController', // <-- I link to my controller and avoid adding the controller code here.
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: false,
    scope: {
      user: '=checkbox'
    },
    template: '<label for="addressSame" class="form-label col-md-2" style="width: auto;">Same as Buyers Address</label><input type="checkbox" name="addressSame" ng-click="isSameAddress()" ng-model="isChecked" />'
  }
}
```

This would allow you to get the outer controller's `user` value into your directive through the `checkbox` attribute. This value is then accessed in your Directive JS code through the `$scope.user` property. Like this:

```
<div checkbox="user"></div>
```